# Android Signed APK

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, уважаемые Хешкодовцы )

Вот такая проблема у нас. Был фрилансер, который делал АПК. Выложили АПК на гугл плей. 
Возникла необходимость внести правки в АПК, что, собственно, и сделали.

Но вот проблема:
 1. Фрилансера нет, и связаться нет возможности.
 2. Сигнед ключей для подписи АПК нет (тех, которыми был подписан апп).  
 3. Как быть? Сгенерировать новый ключ? Как это воспримет гугл плей?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Залить обновление, подписанное другим ключем **невозможно**. Абсолютно невозможно.  
Что же делать?

- Найти все-таки фрилансера, который это делал, и выбить у него ключ
- Залить приложение заново с новым package

П. С. восстановить утерянный ключ так же невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

"Если вы потеряете ключ загрузки, обратитесь в службу поддержки разработчиков, чтобы сбросить его."
Это можно сделать здесь:
В Google play console выберите проект > Управление релизом > Подписи приложений